# Determination or AR and MA parameters

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, finance

I have in my possession price and time of different trade from an auction. The price series isn't stationnary so I work with the log return series. I'd like to forecast the evolution of the log return series thanks to models such as AR, MA and ARMA. 
To identify the parameters of AR and MA models, I used the ACF and PACF plots. However, I don't understand their signification because they're almost identical.
I know how to find the p and q parameters from these plots but in this case, I don't know how to do it and which of the models can be use.

Here is a picture of the ACF and PACF plot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhbFj.jpg

Comment: "The price series isn't stationnary so I work with the log return series." Whether the price is stationary or not has nothing to do with whether you are interested in log(price) or not.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough autocorrelation in your series. Did you try a Durbin-Watson or Ljung-Box test to see whether it's possible to use a time series method at all?

Comment: @Digio It is not only possible to use time series models (e.g., error correction models) with stationary data, it can actually be desirable to do so. See Boef, S. D., & Keele, L. (2008). [Taking Time Seriously](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a3e/d25148f942dc6038a1fb45bcb759575106a4.pdf). *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1), 184–200.

Comment: @Alexis, obviously. But the Ljung-Box test is for autocorrelation, not stationarity, two different things. How would you go about modelling time information when there's not enough of it?

Comment: @Alexis, regarding your first comment, log indeed is irrelevant; the key word is *returns*, i.e. not the level of price but its first difference.

Comment: @Digio Autocorrelation (weakly stationary) and nonstationary (unit-root or larger) processes are not unrelated: they are *both* processes in which a variable has *memory* of its past value(s). My view is that because weakly stationary processes may return to a stationary equilibrium at a time scale longer than the actual data were observed, timer series models (error correction models) should be used for time series data.

Comment: @RichardHardy You are quite right, and I blipped right over the 'returns' bit.

Comment: I would recommend to take the same plots with a differenced series and try to fit ARIMA.

Comment: @Alexis, I did not mean to imply that they're completely unrelated. While it is true that autocorrelation is only meaningful in the scenario of wide sense stationarity, one does not infer the other. A process is covariance-stationary or weakly stationary when its first and second moments are time invariant. The autocorrelation coefficient $cov(y_t, y_{t-k}) \over {\sigma_{y_t}\sigma_{y_{t-k}}}$ will only infer $cov(y_t, y_{t-k}) \over {var(y_t)}$ if the process is wide sense stationary. In the opposite case, you'll have a non-stationary process with autocorrelation.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, yes I tried a Ljung-Box test on Matlab and the answer was positive i.e there is a correlation between the values. I'll try another ACF and PACF plots on other data to see the difference. Thanks again